# Changing textview visibility in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, if-statement, visibility, onitemclicklistener

I want to click to hide or unhide a textview using android studio. If it is visible, one click will make it invisible. If it is invisible, one click will make it visible.

Currently, only half of the function is working. While I can click to make a textview invisible, clicking it again does not make it visible again.

Here is my code

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toDoList = new ArrayList<>();
        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.list_view_layout, toDoList);
        listView = findViewById(R.id.id_list_view);

        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id){
                TextView textView = (TextView) view;

                if (textView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                    textView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
                else {
                    textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

            }
        });
```

When trying to debug it, I find that the else statement is never ran, even when the if condition returns false. Am I missing something?

Comment: You are making it invisible ... then on which view you are clicking ? The view is already invisible so it did't detect any touches i.e touches won't work on invisible views

Comment: I agree with @PraveenSP It has already gone invisible so technically it can't detect any gestures while it's invisible unless you wrap it with another view that also detects the gestures but doesn't get hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get extViw from your onItemClick is wrong.

```
 TextView textView = (TextView) view;
```

it should be

```
TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.yourTextView);
```

and if you want to invisible view and clickable, use setAlpha(0); and setAlpha(1);

Comment: No, invisible views also be clickable, your issue is caused by the view's click event intercepted by other view.But the answer is fine.